# Read/Forward properties of other GradleBuild Task

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to build a gradle plugin which has 2 tasks, both of type `GradleBuild` and both calling several other tasks. It looks like this

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {

        project.task('first', type: GradleBuild) {
            startParameter = project.getGradle().startParameter.newInstance()

            tasks = [
                'doSmth',
                'second'
            ]
        }

        project.task('second', type: GradleBuild) {
            startParameter = project.getGradle().startParameter.newInstance()

            tasks = [
                'doSmthOther',
            ]
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

and on the commandline I start my *first* task

```
gradle first
```

Now as `GradleBuild` tasks are basically launching a complete new instance, all project properties which are set in the task *doSmth* (e.g. `project.ext.myvalue=true`) are not accessible in *doSmthOther*.

How can I transfer all or certain project properties which are set inside of the *doSmth* tasks to the *doSmthOther* task?